# How to create and destroy widgets dynamically with tkinter?

Tags: python, class, object, tkinter

I tried to create up to 5 inputboxes selecting a value in a combobox, but once I try to build the widgets again I get this error _tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!label3" in line 29

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class InputBox:
    def __init__(self, master, row):
        self.label = ttk.Label(master, text=f"Input box {row}:")
        self.label.grid(row=row, column=0)
        self.entry = ttk.Entry(master)
        self.entry.grid(row=row, column=1)

    def destroy(self):
        self.label.destroy()
        self.entry.destroy()

class ComboBox:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.combo_box = ttk.Combobox(master, values=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
        self.combo_box.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.combo_box.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.create_input_boxes)
        self.input_boxes = []

    def create_input_boxes(self, event):
        num_boxes = int(self.combo_box.get())
        for i in range(num_boxes):
            if i >= len(self.input_boxes):
                input_box = InputBox(root, i+1)
                self.input_boxes.append(input_box)
            else:
                self.input_boxes[i].label.grid()
                self.input_boxes[i].entry.grid()

        for i in range(num_boxes, len(self.input_boxes)):
            self.input_boxes[i].destroy()

root = tk.Tk()
combo_box = ComboBox(root)

root.mainloop()
```

I tried to make it build and destroy the widgets to make, but once destroyed they can't be built again. Besides that, I'll later add a button to get what's in the inputboxes

Comment: The problem is that `self.input_boxes[i].destroy()` doesn't remove the widget from the `list` and because it's in the list, it tries to call `self.input_boxes[i].label.grid()` on a destroyed widget.